# WebGL / Three.js boundaries of values

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm creating a galaxy with Three.js and i'm trying to set everything in realistic scale. Therefor values for position and size can get really big.

So those values i'm handeling with, are in range of 0 up to ~ 1 * 10^20.
However, i noticed that values > ~ 1*10^6 and < ~ 1*10^-5 cause issues, for example [`visibility`](https://jsfiddle.net/fees9768/5/), raycasting and other stuff.

So is there a limit how big or small values can be? Or are problems related to something else and can be avoided by using a trick.

Comment: Can maybe [math.js](http://mathjs.org/) help out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

be sure to look at this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=depth#webgl_camera_logarithmicdepthbuffer)

because of the big values, you should use a logarithmic depth buffer.

when initializing your renderer with

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({logarithmicDepthBuffer: true });
```

your fiddle should work perfectly

i dont know about raycasting, but it should cause no problems. especcially if you do it over the [gpu](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes_gpu), as the result should be equal to the rendered image

Comment: Actually a have seen this example long time ago, but didnt thought about that anymore.
Thank you so much, that will solve a lot of problems!